# Emacs — Top User Swag!

Tags: discussion

**We want to congratulate and thank everyone that helped this site and community grow healthily into what they are today!**

If you can find your name among the top 72 users in the first two pages [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), we have a surprise for you! We want to send you a token of our appreciation for being among the most prolific users in this community! As such, we're sending you a little box, inside which you'll find:

**A T-SHIRT!**

[image: T-SHIRTS!!!!!!!]

**STICKERS!**

[image: STICKERS!!!!!!!]

I'll be reaching out to you later today with a link to a form: be sure to fill out the form as soon as you're able to do so! You'll have two weeks to do it, after which I'll close the form and take care of sending all of the swag your way! It should take from 6 to 8 weeks for the package to be delivered to you!

If you're not on the list, don't worry too much about it — we've got some extra swag stored we can send to you for events and such!

**Thanks to all of you for making this site great!**

Comment: It was such a pleasant surprise to receive your email this afternoon. Just another reminder that this is my favorite SO community to participate in, as well as one of the healthiest, most helpful and encouraging sites in my opinion.

Comment: Does such giveaway also happen for other stackexchange/stackoverlfow sites?

Comment: Sure, @Tim: just [look in the Metas for "top user swag"](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=top+user+swag) and you'll find 'em — we do these when a site graduates and their own design rolls out.

Comment: @JNat  Have you sent out the t shirts yet? My mailing address will not be good after this month.

Comment: I haven't, @Tim, no. If it won't be good after a month, maybe resubmit the form, and I'll keep the most recent entry when I review the entries :)

Comment: @JNat Have you sent out the t shirts yet? I sent you an email a month ago after my last comment with my updated address. I hope you have got it.

Comment: I don't believe these have been shipped yet, @Tim. But I did update your address, yeah.

Comment: Received my swag today, it's really awesome.  Thank you so much, for providing us with this great space to help each other, and for the great swag.   ❤️

Comment: Got them in the mailbox yesterday. Very good surprise because I had forgotten about this story already. Thank you so much ! Ok, now, wearing a T shirt is easy... but I need to decide where to put the stickers!

Comment: Ditto. Thanks for the shirt!